# Is there a way to decide whether a differential equation is solvable or not?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logic, computability

Martin Davis, Yuri Matiyasevich, Hilary Putnam and Julia Robinson had negatively settled Hilbert 10th problem, I wonder if there is an analog result to the differential equations ?

Comment: That partially comes down to the question: Is there a way to decide whether an integral is "computable (i.e. has an anti derivative in terms of elementary functions) or not. And my inclination is: No

Comment: Certainly no algorithm for systems of ODE, or single PDE.  Need to go, will answer if there is none when I return.

Answer (score 5):

There is newer stuff, but you can find a partial answer in an old short paper *Some Recursively Unsolvable Problems in Analysis* (Adler, AMS Proceedings, 1969). It is shown that there is no algorithm for determining the solvability of systems of algebraic differential equations. This is done by a reduction to the result by Davis, Putnam, Robinson on the nonexistence of an algorithm for determining whether an exponential Diophantine equation has a solution.